# Material UI changes style of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Every time I render component, it's keep changing styles.

```html
import React from 'react';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import sharedTheme from '../../styling/theme.js';
import { Icon } from '@twilio/flex-ui';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { makeInternalCall } from './index';
import { StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = theme => (sharedTheme(theme));

class InternalDialpad extends React.Component {
.........

render() {
        const { classes, manager } = this.props;
        const { contact_uri: worker_contact_uri } =
            manager.workerClient.attributes;

        return (
            <div className={classes.boxDialpad}>
                <div className={classes.titleAgentDialpad}>Call Agent</div>
                <div className={classes.subtitleDialpad}>Select agent</div>
                <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                    <Select
                        value={this.state.selectedWorker}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        isClearable
                    >
                        {this.state.workerList.map((worker)=> {
                                const { activity_name } = worker;
                                const { contact_uri, full_name } = worker.attributes;

                                return (
                                    contact_uri !== worker_contact_uri && 
                                    activity_name !== "Offline" 
                                ) ? (
                                    <MenuItem value={contact_uri} key={contact_uri}>
                                        {full_name}
                                    </MenuItem>
                                ) : null
                            }
                        )}
                    </Select>
                    <div className={classes.buttonAgentDialpad}>
                        <Button 
                            variant="contained" 
                            color="primary" 
                            disabled={!this.state.selectedWorker} 
                            onClick={this.makeCall}
                            className={classes.dialPadBtn}
                        >
                            <Icon icon="Call"/>
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </FormControl>
            </div>
        )
            }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(InternalDialpad);
```

Theme.js

```html
const sharedTheme = (theme) => ({

root: {
flexGrow: 1,
display: "flex",
flexWrap: "wrap",
},
main:{
  margin: 0,
  padding: 0
},
formControl: {
  width: "250px",
},
boxDialpad: {
  borderTop: "1px solid #eeeeee",
},
titleAgentDialpad: {
  width: "100%",
  textTransform: "uppercase",
  textAlign: "center",
  fontWeight: "bold",
  fontSize: theme.typography.fontSize,
},
subtitleDialpad: {
  textTransform: "uppercase",
},
buttonAgentDialpad: {
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
},
dialPadBtn: {
  borderRadius: "100px",
  minWidth: "0px",
}
});
```

Now as expected, I can see styles classes are being assigned to each elements, but as soon as I render this component , it changes it's class name or add similar class to that element with additional css styles. Not sure why it is happening.

[image: First time I render this component]
[image: Second time]

Answer (score 0):

Material UI components are native HTML elements with additional styles applied as classes in order for them to achieve the clean look that they have out of the box.

Using the component `<Button />` for instance is just shorthand for the MUI custom Button component implementation, which includes a native `<input type="button" />`, several `<div />`s, and more. Look in your browser dev tools at what renders to the DOM where you imported the MUI elements in your JSX.

The styles you are adding via `classes.customClassName` extends that default, but is not the only styling on the element. If you need to override these defaults, you can see which classes will be added to each element during render in [the API section of each MUI component's documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button/#css).